# pass image from python to android (kotlin)

Tags: python, android, kotlin, chaquopy

I've created an Android app that takes a photo, then sends it to a python script to do some processing and other stuff. But I'm stuck because I'm unsure how I would send the image back to Android to view it...

I'm using Chaquopy to pass the image to my python script

This is how I send the image to python:

```
            val byteBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer
            val bytes = ByteArray(byteBuffer.capacity())
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
            val byteOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteOutputStream)
            val image = byteOutputStream.toByteArray()
            val py = Python.getInstance()
            val pyObject = py.getModule("run")
            val result = pyObject.callAttr("main", image)
```

I need the image to be viewable in Android

Answer (score 0):

The Python function should return a `bytes` object containing an image file in PNG or JPEG format. This can then be displayed in an `ImageView` as follows:

```
val resultBytes = result.toJava(ByteArray::class.java)
val resultBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(resultBytes, 0, resultBytes.size)
imageView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap)
```

There's a full example of this in the [chaquopy-matplotlib](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-matplotlib) demo.