# Meshgrid-android studio

Tags: java, android, chaquopy

Is there a secret library for android studio, in which I will find the meshgrid function? Or a likewise library, where I could build upon my meshgrid function. Because I want to make a photo via the camera, after that the meshgrid of the photo (in greyscale) should be displayed in the imageView. Please help me or give me a hint.

I also ask myself, how should I code this to so it fits all together?

I will try it solving it with a python script within the java code, though I want to hear your opinion first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're familiar with Python, it should be possible to do this using Chaquopy and NumPy. For details of how to pass images to and from Python, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74936976).